# vb 6.0 delete row from listview1

Tags: vb6

I just joined the site, I apologize in advance for the wrong English, I used google translate,
I used listview1 in vb 6, there is no problem with adding and deleting by clicking
What I want to do is to remove the number I wrote in the txtsearch.Text box on the form from the list, not index, it will only remove what I wrote in the txtsearch.Text box.

it should be like in the picture

[image]

i tried this but it only deletes as index it doesn't delete the line i wrote

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

If ListView1.ListItems.Count <= 0 Then MsgBox "Nothing to remove", vbInformation, "": Exit Sub
ListView1.SelectedItem = ListView1.ListItems(Val(txtsearch.Text))
        If vbYes = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected item?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "") Then
            ListView1.ListItems.Remove (ListView1.SelectedItem.Index)
End If

End Sub
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Please do not add additional information in answers.  Edit the new information into the question.

Comment: Turns out he question is actually how to find a listitem (row) that contains a specified value.  To do this use the FindItem method of the listview control.  This also makes this a duplicate question, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21359441/162313.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB6.0 Comparing Date to a data in Listview subitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359441/vb6-0-comparing-date-to-a-data-in-listview-subitem)

Comment: Please do not answer comments by posting answers. Answer are reserved only for actual solutions to the problem. If you want to respond to a comment [edit] the question to incorporate the suggestions and provide the details that comments asked for. Then mark comments as no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

To select a desired row via the SelectedItem property, the `Set` keyword must be used.

Alternatively, the `Selected` property for the desired row can be set to True in order to select that row.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
  If ListView1.ListItems.Count <= 0 Then 
    MsgBox "Nothing to remove", vbInformation, ""
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set ListView1.SelectedItem = ListView1.ListItems(Val(txtsearch.Text))
  ' Or the following will also work
  'ListView1.ListItems(Val(txtsearch.Text)).Selected = True

  If vbYes = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected item?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "") Then
    ListView1.ListItems.Remove (ListView1.SelectedItem.Index)
  End If
End Sub
```